# Porque no funciona el clearInterval en un componenete de class de react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

BUen dia tengo el siguiente componente y quiero usar un boton de STAR/STOP que inicie y detenga un setInterval, he intentando diversas formas y nisiquiera la mas extensa y simple me quiere funcionar. en algun lugar lei que el .this tiene conflicto con setInterval pero he intentado todo lo q he podido.

si alguien pudiera ayudar muchas gracias de antemano

```
class App extends React.Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {      
            session: 25,
            break: 15,
            play: false,
            type: ["SESSION","BREAK"],
            timeleft:1500
        } 

      this.breakDecrement=this.breakDecrement.bind(this)

      } 
      

    breakDecrement(){
       if(this.state.break>1)
       this.setState(a=>({break: a.break-1}))
     } 

      
    reset(){
       this.setState({
          session: 25,
            break: 15,
            play: false
        })
      }
    startStop(){
       let temporizador=null 
      if(!this.state.play){
        this.setState(a=>({play: !a.play})) 
        temporizador = setInterval(()=>{
          this.breakDecrement()
        },1000)
        console.log(this.state.break+" "+this.state.play+" start") 
      }
      else{      
        console.log(this.state.break+" "+this.state.play+" stop")  
        clearInterval(temporizador) **//este clearintervalo pareciera no estar funcionando**
        temporizador=null
        this.setState(a=>({play: !a.play}))  
      }   
    }
         
      render(){  
        return(  
          <div className="general">      
            <button id="start_stop" onClick={this.startStop}>START/STOP</button>
            <button id="reset" onClick={this.reset}>RESET</button>        
          </div>
        )
      }
     }               
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('g'))
```

Answer (score 0):

YA consegui la solucion, resulta ser q setInterval retorna una especie de ID si setInterval modifica el state react Bugea porq este ID cambia. por lo tanto hay q manejarlo y adecuarlo si setInterval esta modificando el state.

[aqui hay 2 explicaciones de como manejarlo por Ciclos de Vida y por onClick]
: https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react-class/

```
    class App extends React.Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {      
            session: 25,
            break: 15,
            play: false,
           intervalId:0                
        } 

      this.breakDecrement=this.breakDecrement.bind(this)

      }           

    breakDecrement(){
       if(this.state.break>1)
       this.setState(a=>({break: a.break-1}))
     }     
      
    reset(){
       this.setState({
          session: 25,
            break: 15,
            play: false,
            intervalId:0
        })
      }
    startStop(){
     if(this.state.intervalId){ //verifica true intervalId
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId); //aqui detiene el setInterval
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
           ...prevState,
           intervalId: 0,
          };
        });
     return; //este RETURN todavia no lo entiendo
    }
  
  const newIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        break: prevState.break- 1,
      };
    });
  }, 1000);
  
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      intervalId: newIntervalId,
    };
  });
  
    }
         
      render(){  
        return(  
          <div className="general">      
            <button id="start_stop" onClick={this.startStop}>START/STOP</button>
            <button id="reset" onClick={this.reset}>RESET</button>        
          </div>
        )
      }
     }               
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('g'))
```

podemos observarcomo el metodo start/stop verifica o modifica el ID y detiene el setInterval dependiendo. (hay un return q no me queda claro como funciona)